# Cast variable to use as index (Metal Shading language)

Tags: ios, metal

I'm trying to use a floating point variable as index to access the position of a MTLBuffer but I have to cast it to unsigned int. Well, that's my first thought.

In practice this doesn't seem to work but I don't quite understand why.

I basically have something like:

```
vertex VertexOut basic_vertex(const device float3 *vertex_array   [[ buffer(0) ]],
                              const device float3 *color_array    [[ buffer(1) ]], 
(...))
{

   // get the current vertex
   float3 position = vertex_array[vid];
   // get the color index
   uint color_index = as_type<uint>(position.z);
   // get the color
   float3 color = color_array[color_index];

   VertexOut vertexOut;
   vertexOut.position = proj_Matrix * mv_Matrix * float4(position.x, position.y, 0, 1);
   vertexOut.color = float4(color, 1);
   return vertexOut;
}
```

I'm trying to reduce the amount of data to be sent to the GPU by using the Z coordinate to index the color buffer, instead of repeating the same color for a large amount of vertices. This way, instead of passing 6 floats (x,y,z,r,g,b) I just have to pass 3 plus the colours .

The error I got is not when I'm using the *color_index* variable to get the color. The problem is when I try to access the color, for instance:

```
vertexOut.color = float4(color, 1);
```

If I do that I will get this error:

```
Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Hang Error (IOAF code 3)
```

Is there any work around for what I'm trying to accomplish?
What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `as_type` is functionally equivalent to C++'s `reinterpret_cast`: it literally treats the bits of the source value as if they were the provided type, which is incorrect in this context. What you probably want instead is something like `floor`, or no cast at all (i.e. you can initialize the index with a float, and the (expensive) float-to-uint conversion will happen implicitly). The fact that you don't get this error when not accessing the color probably indicates that the array access is getting dead-code eliminated when the resulting value is unused.

Comment: Thank you @warrenm, this solved the problem.I just had to remove the type cast and use the `floor` instead. It didn't occur to me that `as_type` was equivalent to `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Happy to help; I've posted my comment as an answer if you'd like to accept it.

Comment: I've accepted the answer.Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as_type` is functionally equivalent to C++'s `reinterpret_cast`: it literally treats the bits of the source value as if they were the provided type, which is incorrect in this context. What you probably want instead is something like `floor`, or no cast at all (i.e. you can initialize the index with a `float`, and the (expensive) `float`-to-`uint` conversion will happen implicitly). The fact that you don't get this error when not accessing the color probably indicates that the array access is getting dead-code eliminated when the resulting value is unused.